# Which regression model should I build?

Tags: regression, bayesian, generalized-linear-model, multinomial-distribution, dirichlet-process

I'm trying to handle a dataset about student performance in 2 Portuguese Schools in the subject of Portuguese.

Student grades go from 0 to 20, discrete. I have a set of 30 Regressors (all but 3 numerical, the other categorical)and 3 response variables (student grades after first, second and third semester). I would like to conduct a Bayesian Analysis over the dataset. As such I thought about a blueprint like this one:

Building a linear semiconjugate model, with priors over Beta|Sig^2 and Sig^2 being a P-variate normal (P= number of regressors +1) and an Inverse-Gamma. 
Given that I don't have any prior literature I was considering to use the OLS estimate of the coefficients as mean of the normal distribution and the Sig^2 Ols as estimate of the mean of the inverse gamma one (even if that is not strictly bayesian as I use data for the prior). In alternative I would use the Zellner G prior. 
The response would be just one of the 3 scores.
Since the first is not a completely bayesian model and the second uses no information a priori I was wondering how to use some of the information available in literature regarding the strong correlation between parents education/job/status(divorced or not) to build a prior on Betas. Unfortunately I don't have a priori information over all 30 predictors so I'm puzzled.

The other linear model I would build is a generalized one, where the response y is now multinomial (21 levels), but I don't have a clue on which model to implement between a cumulative logit/probit and I find it hard to picture a bayesian model behind it (may be a Dirichlet Process? ) .

The dataset is here: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Student+Performance

I just transformed the variables MotherEducation, FatherEducation, MotherJob and Father Job (with k levels) into k-1 dummies given there is no mathematical meaning to the number associated to the level.

Comment: I performed various tests on the normality of my response variable, all giving me positive answer. The lm model constructed including all the predictors has a low R2 (33%-39%), the cum logits and cum links model have an even higher AIC..

Comment: Fun problem: An $R^2$ in the area of $33-39\%$ is not low unless you have good reasons to believe that it should be higher. For example, you do not have sibling parity information (just family size) and that is generally associated with children's IQ, etc. I would also note that especially educational has a clear ordinal categorization so it should have an additive effect. Finally you could be an empirical Bayesian on this: just use your data to fit your priors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. Yeah, I know R2 is not the most reliable metric, especially given the high amount of units and the fact that the predictors of school performance could be in an infinite number.. 
Introducing some possible correlation factors I didn't improve the model that much (still using R2 as a metric), so your hypothesis about additive effect seems fitting..

Comment: I just played quickly around with your data. Check `e1071::svm` with a `radial` basis. In terms of both MSE and MAE (Median Absolute Error) it come out the best (predicting `G3`). This was without fixing the encoding parental education, so probably you could squeeze something more of this too.

Comment: Thank you again, I'm trying to go a little bit into vector machines.. I'll use it as an upper bound for my prediction results, even if the main purpose is not necessarily a comparison in terms of predictions ..